# which was the first platform independent programming language

Tags: java

I wanna know ... which was the first platform independent programming language?

I think it is Java but I cannot confirm. I have tried searching on the internet but have not found any solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking through some articles, Lisp seems to beat Java, as Lisp came out in around 1958. Python also beats Java by a couple years.

Comment: Ah that's right. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

FORTRAN was the first, dating from 1954.

Lisp was only implemented in 1958.

Source: Wikipedia
[Programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language).

Comment: [The first FORTRAN compiler was delivered in April 1957](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran#History)